# Can I plug a Raspberry Pi Pico (5 Vdc) to an ATX 2.4?

Tags: atx, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a Corsair SF450 (ATX 2.4) not connected to any PC motherboard; however, I believe it's providing a 5 VDC supply to the mini-USB, by the ATX pin 6 or 4 for (+) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#ATX12V_2.x); in that case I can any other ground as (-).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes, connecting to 5V and ground wires of an ATX supply provides 5V to your circuit.

In practice, there are a few issues. The first one is that the power supply won't provide the main output rails before it is turned on by your circuit. When it is in standby, the only output is the standby 5V which may not provide enough current.

A second, but more larger issue is, that ATX power supplies are generally not ideal for custom hobby projects. They can have problems if you only load one output and have no load at all on other outputs. They may not turn on or stay on with no or very low load. And they may turn off if you suddenly remove all or most load it has. So as a workaround, extra dummy load resistors and capacitors may need to be added to each output rail.

Comment: I'm prototyping an industrial project. Do you have harder data than "may", maybe with references ? Or does it depend on the implementation (ie., which actual ATX PSU),.

Comment: Of course it depends on the PSU. If you search this site or google about it, you will see people asking why their ATX supplies won't work. If you really want just 5V for Raspberry Pi, buy a real power supply. An USB charger if you just want to prototype and don't need a lot of power or an industrial power supply if you actually want to build an industrial prototype. Also if your load does not draw power according to ATX specs, then it can't be used as operation is not guaranteed outside specs.